# req.body is giving me undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created a controller which has the following code:

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        const user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email
        });

        user.save((err, user) => {
            if (err)
                console.error(err);

            res.send(user);
        });
    })
```

I'm using Postman to post a new entry through `/users` endpoint, but I get an error everytime I do it: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.
Body sent:

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "email": "example@gmail.com"
}
```

Trying to debug it, I printed the value of req.body in the console, as you actually see in the code. It gives me `undefined`.
I want to mention that I do have these included in `app.js` generated by Express CLI:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I want to mention that I do have these included:"* where? What contentType are you sending with the request?

Comment: In the main app.js, right after I open a connection with mongoose. https://i.imgur.com/V2uaUp1.png

Comment: The post you are sending looks correct, can you log the request headers that express sees?

Comment: Here's everything req outputs: https://pastebin.com/EKMGLLBR

Comment: Ok, so,  here's the symptoms: req.body contains `undefined`. According to the documentation, if the json middleware is used (aka the contentType was application/json) req.body would be an empty object, or an object containing data, even if the data was invalid or an error occurred. The fact that it is undefined leads me to believe the middleware isn't running before this route is defined. Can you show where in your code the middleware is relative to your post route?

Comment: I'm actually learning from a book, so the code for routes (in book called controllers) is above parsers: https://i.imgur.com/jKbhAVI.png. OK, so I changed the order, now the code for including the controllers is below those parsers and it's working. Great analyzing, thank you very much for the answer, you can post it, so I can check it as solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the fact that `req.body` is `undefined` and you have the correct contentType, I would suggest looking at the order of your middleware vs routes. Middleware must come before any routes that depend on it.

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the body parser to the express app ?
Try using the body parser module if not

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```